# How to connect an HTML GUI with a Java back-end, without hosting a server?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, css, web

I am required to develop a MySQL database application with some GUI requirements which are efficiently met with HTML and CSS. So I am using HTML and CSS for the GUI.

I want to use Java programming language for connection with the database and other back-end functionality.

Most importantly, I do not want to host any kind of server.

*So somebody has put this idea into my head: Use java for the back-end database connection, write a web service for your code, use HTML5/CSS3 for the GUI, and JavaScript to consume the web-service. 
(I hope I got it right and I am saying it right)*

**Please tell me if this is possible**, and if this involves having some sort of a server or not. I want these three things:

1. Back-end in Java
2. GUI in HTML
3. No server

**Is there a way?**

Comment: Where would the HTML and CSS be hosted? Where would the database be hosted? Where would the web service be hosted? Is this just something you want to use locally on one computer, or something you want to be available on the web?

Comment: @MikeB Yes, want to use it locally on one computer!

Comment: It's possible to do it the way you're thinking but you'll still need a web server running on your machine. I would just use JavaFX for the UI, then it's Java all the way down and you don't need to worry about running a web server.

Comment: @MikeB I was initially thinking about JavaFX, but I am a noob and I have heard that it is very difficult. I want some transitions and animations in the GUI. Do you think doing that will be appropriate for a beginner?

Comment: If you're experienced enough with HTML and CSS to do those things I don't think learning how to do it in JavaFX will be very difficult for you. Good tutorials here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm